# How would I rewrite a directory from any domain to another directory on the same domain?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

### The Setup

I am using Wordpress Multisite, and I have each of the sub sites set up with their own domain. So for example, I have:

- example.com (Main Wordpress Install)

  - example1.com
  - example2.com
  - example3.com

Where each of the example sites are not real directories, but just rewrites.

The Wordpress uploads directory in these cases look like **http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/** Where **2** is the blog id.

### The question

I would like to give each of these sites a *real* directory in their domain that they could upload files to *outside* of wordpress. Something like:

*http://example2.com/files/*

What Rewrite Rules would I need in the .htaccess file to rewrite any url with the path **sitename.com**/files/ to example.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/files/**sitename.com**/

### What I Tried

Well, I'm pretty worthless at mod_rewrite rules, but I gave this a go with no luck:

```
RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST}/files/(.*) "http\:\/\/example\.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/files/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1" [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^.]+\.[^.]+(\..*)?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^files/?$ /wp-content/uploads/sites/files/%1/ [NC,L]
```

We first exclude the main domain, then capture the non-www part of the add-on domains and rewrite to the corresponding sub-directory.

Comment: Thank you! But, it should only match the condition if the non-www part of the add-on domain is **/files/**.  Everything else should go past these conditions to the Wordpress rewrite rules.

Comment: Please give actual sample URLs. It's unclear what you're asking because a domain name can never have / in it. Only url path can.